# How I can access to the "Text" Property of a ListView LayoutTemplate Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, text, controls

I have a ASP.NET Application and use a `ListView`. This `ListView` has a `LayoutTemplate`,`ItemTemplate` and a `AlternatingItemTemplate`. In My `LayoutTemplate` I have `LinkLabels`. I want to make a Multilanguage Page and I must access to The `Text` Property of this `Linklabels`. But I don't can access to this Property.

My ASPX (ListView)

```
<LayoutTemplate>
    <table id="UserTable" runat="server" border="0">
        <tr id="Tr1" style="background-color:#E5E5FE">
            <th runat="server"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBenutzer" runat="server" >id_Benutzer</asp:LinkButton></th>
            <th runat="server"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkemail" runat="server" >id_Email</asp:LinkButton></th>
            <th runat="server"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkVorname" runat="server" >id_Vorname</asp:LinkButton></th>
            <th runat="server"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkNachname" runat="server" >id_Nachname</asp:LinkButton></th>
            <th runat="server"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkTelefon" runat="server" >id_Telefon</asp:LinkButton></th>
        </tr>
        <tr runat="server" id="ItemPlaceholder">
        </tr>
    </table>
</LayoutTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>

    <tr> 

        <td align="left" ><asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%# Eval("Benutzername") %>' runat="server" /></td>
        <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label2" Text='<%# Eval("eMail") %>' runat="server" /></td>
        <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label3" Text='<%# Eval("Vorname") %>' runat="server" /></td>
        <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label4" Text='<%# Eval("Nachname") %>' runat="server" /></td>
        <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label5" Text='<%# Eval("Telefonnummer") %>' runat="server" /></td>

     <td align="left"><asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Anzeigen" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'  runat="server" /></td>

      <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label6" Text='<%# Eval("GUID") %>' runat="server" Visible="False" /></td>


    </tr>

</ItemTemplate>

<AlternatingItemTemplate>

    <tr style="background-color:#EFEFEF"> 

        <td align="left" ><asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%# Eval("Benutzername") %>' runat="server" /></td>
        <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label2" Text='<%# Eval("eMail") %>' runat="server" /></td>
        <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label3" Text='<%# Eval("Vorname") %>' runat="server" /></td>
        <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label4" Text='<%# Eval("Nachname") %>' runat="server" /></td>
        <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label5" Text='<%# Eval("Telefonnummer") %>' runat="server" /></td>

    <td align="left"><asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Anzeigen" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'  runat="server" /></td>

        <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label6" Text='<%# Eval("GUID") %>' runat="server" Visible="False" /></td>

    </tr>

</AlternatingItemTemplate>
```

My C# code:

```
        if (lang == "de")
        {
            string xmlfile= "de_language.xml"; 
                              //GetXMLElement() is my Method
            id_SearchUser.Text = GetXMLElement(xmlfile, "id_SearchUser");
            id_location.Text = GetXMLElement(xmlfile, "id_location");
            Button2.Text = GetXMLElement(xmlfile, "id_Search");

                        //I must access to the text property
            //lnkBenutzer.text = GetXMLElement(xmlfile, "User"); 
        }
```

My Button:

```
protected void Button1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Select")
            {
                //Der Index der Zeile wird ermitellt
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

                string xmlfile = Session["language_file"].ToString(); 
               //it doen't works :( 
                ((LinkButton)myListView.FindControl("lnkBenutzer")).Text = GetXMLElement(xmlfile, "id_User");

                //Der Inhalt (GUID[Unsichtbar]) wird aus der zeile mit dem Index herausgezogen und übergeben       

                Label lb = (Label)myListView.Items[index].FindControl("Label6");

                //Der GUID, Benutzer-Nachname und das Werk werden an eine Session übergeben
                Session["UserID"] = lb.Text;
                Session["SearchUser"] = txtBenutzer.Text;
                Session["DropDownValue"] = dropWerk.SelectedValue;

                //Es wird eine neue Webform geöffnet
                Response.Redirect("Benutzer.aspx");

            }

        }
```

Comment: Can I ask you why you're using a listview to display some prefixed buttons though?

Comment: This Webinterface show a list of Users and with this Buttons I can display more Information about a User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to do something like the following:

In your Benutzer.aspx:

```
public void Page_Load() {
    string xmlfile = Session["language_file"].ToString(); 
    LinkButton lnkBenutzer = (LinkButton)myListView.FindControl("lnkBenutzer");
    lnkBenutzer.Text = GetXMLElement(xmlfile, "User"); 
}
```

In short what you need to do is "find" the list view control and then find the control inside the list view. This could be shortened to:

```
((LinkButton)myListView.FindControl("lnkBenutzer")).Text = GetXMLElement(xmlfile, "User");
```

Going further you could extract this to a method wherein you pass in your item name and the new text :

```
public void SetText(string controlName, string text)
{
    ((LinkButton)myListView.FindControl(controlName)).Text = text;
}
```

then you could call:

```
SetText("lnkBenutzer", GetXMLElement(xmlfile, "User"));
```

replacing your names and vales as required.

Comment: The Object reference don't set to an object instance :(  I get the ListView after I cklick a Button :(

Comment: Could you post more code I might be able to spot where it needs to go?

Comment: What does your button that makes the ListView visible do - redirect to another page with the listview on? Where is the "My C# code:" code block from is it from a master page or a different page from the ListView control?

Comment: Ahh OK I see the problem - the redirect line at the bottom - you need to run the set text code on the page you're redirecting to Benutzer.aspx - probably in the Page_Load event of that page. Additionally you will also need to copy over the line above - dont remove it from its current location copy both lines into your Benutzer.aspx Page_Load method. I've edited my original suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I think it'll be something like this in codeBehind:

```
LinkButton lb = myListView.FindControl("lnkBenutzer") as LinkButton;
lb.Text = GetXMLElement(xmlfile, "user");
```

Haven't tested it though