# Access Label.text value in a layout template

Tags: c#

How to access and set text of an `asp:label` inside a layout template?

```
<ul class="login_panel">
   <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" RenderOuterTable="false" RememberMeSet="true">
      <LayoutTemplate>
         <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panel1" DefaultButton="LoginButton">
            <li>
              <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName"></asp:Label>
              <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" CssClass=" txt_login" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>                                     
            </li>
         </asp:Panel>
      </LayoutTemplate>
   </asp:Login>
</ul>
```

I need to set the text for label in .cs file.

Comment: What is the parent control of the LayoutTemplate? ListView?

Comment: Razor syntax may have done it easy.

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792799/how-i-can-access-to-the-text-property-of-a-listview-layouttemplate-control

Comment: But I don't have a Listview